# Change the keys for accepting coc dropdown?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-coc

When I type in Vim, I get autocomplete from `coc`.

To accept one of the items on the list I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>.

I would like to change this button to <kbd>Enter</kbd> but I cannot figure out how to do so. I do not mind if it's in lua.

Thanks

Comment: I use the html tag: `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>` it is verbous but it avoid the confusion  induced by `+` for the beginner I was not so long ago ;-)

Comment: Thats really cool. I didnt know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `coc` page (and my `.vimrc` file)

```
" Make <CR> to accept selected completion item or notify coc.nvim to format
" <C-g>u breaks current undo, please make your own choice.
inoremap <silent><expr> <CR> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm()
                              \: "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"
```

Comment: To be clear, in your example the <c-r> ctrl+r accepts an entry?

Comment: That make `<Enter>` accept the entry on the version of `Coc` I use (the latest)

Comment: You are my favorate person right now!! Thanks.